# MongoDB => findOne or find querying next object? ( Meteor / React )

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs

Want to find the next and previous object in relation to current.

**This is what i have**

```
this.props._id = currentId;

// Fetch current object data
data.video = Videos.findOne({_id: this.props._id});

// Using votes string from object above to find me objects 
data.next = Videos.findOne({votes: {$gte: data.video.votes}});
data.previous = Videos.findOne({votes: {$lte: data.video.votes}};
```

I know this is not correct, sure it will return objects but it will not be the nearest object and there is also a chance i will return current object.

What i want to do is to return next or previous object where my selector is votes, I also want to make sure to use Id to exclude current object, then there is also a good chance that several objects will have the same number of votes.

Have been on this for 12 hours straight now and am pretty much back where i started so would really appreciate some examples to make me wrap my head around this, Not sure anymore if i should use find or findOne.

**Here is the complete code**

```
VideoPage = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactMeteorData],
  getMeteorData() {
    var selector = {};
    var handle = Meteor.subscribe('videos', selector);
    var data = {};
    data.userId = Meteor.userId();
    data.video = Videos.findOne({_id: this.props._id});
    data.next = Videos.findOne({votes: {$gte: data.video.votes}});
    data.previous = Videos.findOne({votes: {$lte: data.video.votes}};
    console.log(data.video.votes);
    console.log(data.video);
    console.log(data.next);
    console.log(data.previous);


    return data;
  },


  getContent() {
    return <div>
    {this.data.video.votes}
      <Youtube video={this.data.video} />
    <LikeBox next={this.data.next._id} previous={this.data.previous._id} userId={this.data.userId} video={this.data.video} />
    </div>
    ;
  },


  render() {
    return <div>

      {(this.data.video)? this.getContent() :
        <Loading/>
      }

    </div>;
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to return next or previous object where my selector is votes, and use currentId to exclude current object and use a second selector to sort objects that will be returned with the same value on votes.

Comment: First of all you have to `sort` the cursor...

Comment: @webdeb Yes i was using find and sort but could not get it to work.  Have been testing stuff back and forward for 12h and somehow i manage to fail to get it right and are now back where i started with the code above. 

If i can see a working example it's very easy for me to wrap my head around it, understand it and modify it to suit my case and my code.

Comment: And more or less all other possible options that can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

- exclude the current id
- sort in the appropriate direction
- pick just one result

**js:**

```
data.video = Videos.findOne({ _id: currentId });

// object with next highest vote total
data.next = Videos.findOne({ _id: { $ne: currentId },
  votes: { $gte: data.video.votes }},{ sort: { votes: 1 }});

// object with next lowest vote total
data.previous = Videos.findOne({ _id: { $ne: currentId },
  votes: { $lte: data.video.votes },{ sort: { votes: -1 }});
```

Comment: This actually looks correct, but one little bug.. sort and limit should be in the same object.

Comment: two typos at least, dont copy&paste :)

Comment: Thanks @Michel Floyd 

Running your suggested code will give me the highest and lowest. What am trying to achieve is to get the the object closest to current object.   If current value is 54  and i know i have objects having 53 and 55 i would like to target them. Because there is also several objects with the same number of votes a secondary parameter to solve this must be present.

Comment: sorry for the typos and getting the sort orders backwards, fixed now.

Comment: And yes Mathias, if you have multiple objects with same number of votes then more parameters will be needed to define *nearest*.

Comment: Did change the typos to get it working but as i wrote above it's returning the wrong objects,  If we change the sort parameter and switch value -1 / 1 between them they seem to work better, but they did end up on the object that was having the same number of votes. 

Check this screens, Original 
http://yo.d.pr/1aM2E

Modified 
http://yo.d.pr/1h0M9

Comment: Yes, if there's an object with the same number of votes then it's the *nearest* both above and below. You can change `$gte` and `$lte` to be `$gt` and `$lt` respectively or bring in a second factor to differentiate them.

Comment: Thanks for the code @MichelFloyd, i did figure out that i needed to use $gte / $lte quite early and also to sort it and use $ne but did not manage to write it so it worked, don't know if it was that i was using $ne after sorting.

Comment: @MichelFloyd Could you give me an example where i add a secondary sorting option that will kick in on the results of my firsts one. Because what i have so far with your code is that i make sure currentId is removed, after that i will sort by votes, so if i have several objects with same number of votes, i can use secondary sorting so divide next / previous, but my logics tell me that i need to have something more that tells it to move to next vote number when secondary reaches highest or lowest option there.

Comment: So on secondary i need to use $gt $lt, but also a way for it to go back to first sorting and this time use $gt lt$ or exclude current voting number from the sorting.

Comment: One more question, Why use limit: 1 if am using "findOne" thought that meant only 1 would be returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94653/discussion-between-michel-floyd-and-mathias-asberg).

Answer (score 0):

**I am just like that in Next.js**

```
 const user = await (await User).findOne({ _id: { $ne: "ID HERE" } });
```

OR

```
const user = await User.findOne({ _id: { $ne: "ID HERE" } });
```